# Angularjs js maintining json object on other view

Tags: angularjs, json, object, view, controller

I am adding images to json object in angular without database I am able to add images to json object 'slide', but not able to maintain that json object on other view, though I have same controller for both view.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: There's not enough information to help you. Create a small, executable example of your problem.

Comment: Use a service to share data across various parts of the app

Comment: $scope.selectionslide= []; i am pushing data into this object, after this i want to access this selectionslide object on other view, i have the same controller for both view, but cant access it

Comment: You don't have niether *the same* controller or $scope for both views, so you can't just push and expect it to reflect in other.

Comment: i have PresentationCtrl on both page, i tried using service, but not able to pass json object, i am adding it on ng-click on my images to push data, i can push the data but cant access on other view with same controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Service or a Factory to share your data on your app.

Guide : [Providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)